# Modify PHP class property from another class?

Tags: class, properties

My code:

```
class A{

   function __construct(){
      $foo1 = new Foo1();
      $foo2 = new Foo2();
      $this->copy_property($foo1);           
      $this->copy_property($foo2);           
   }

   private function copy_property($obj){
      foreach (get_object_vars($obj) as $k => $v) $this->$k = $v;
   }
}

$bar = new A();
```

Now my object $bar have all properties from object $foo1 and $foo2
But how can I use method "copy_property" for another classes (B, C, D...) without redefine it?

For example:

```
class B{
   function __construct(){
      $foo3 = new Foo3();
      $foo4 = new Foo4();
      $this->copy_property($foo3);           
      $this->copy_property($foo4); 
   }

   // I must redefine this method here, and class C,D,E...
   private function copy_property($obj){
      foreach (get_object_vars($obj) as $k => $v) $this->$k = $v;
   }
}
$bar2 = new B();
```

P/s: I want to create object foo1, foo2 inside class A, for some reasons

Comment: If using php 5+, $bar = clone $foo;

Comment: It seems you have to do some basics-reading about [inheritance](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php) which will definitely answer your question.

Comment: @varathanyajiv: I can't use "clone" if I create cloned objects inside class A. For some reasons, I can't create them outside. I fixed my code. Wait for your answer

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I can't use "extends" in my case, because I must copy properties from multiple objects ($foo1,$foo2) to my object ($bar). I fixed my code. Wait for your answer

Answer (score 0):

firstly private will not allow you to access the method from other class and secondly convert that function from normal to static or use dependency injection design pattern to achieve your goal.

please change access modifier to public

```
      class A{

       function __construct(){
          $foo1 = new Foo1();
          $foo2 = new Foo2();
          $this->copy_property($foo1);           
          $this->copy_property($foo2);           
       }

        function copy_property($obj){//function access modifier changed
          foreach (get_object_vars($obj) as $k => $v) $this->$k = $v;
       }
    }

    $bar = new A();


        class B{
$aObj;
       function __construct($obj){
         $this->aObj=$obj;
         // now you can run function of class A as
          $this->aObj->copy_property();
       }


    }
    $bar2 = new B($bar);//injecting object of class A from outside
```

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution. Please [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5419867/edit) to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead